# Mapbox custom icon

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

i am using mapbox and i want to add a custom icon on map from my local device. i am using an example:https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/
but i want to pick image or icon from my device or project folder for use. just like.

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage ='../images/icon.png';
    el.style.width = 29 + 'px';
    el.style.height = 29 + 'px';
```

but this is not working. the working line is.
`url(https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/cat.png)`;

Comment: Is your image being served? You are writing client code, and the image path you are trying to reference is a relative path on local on your machine, not the person's running the code. If you properly serve up your image, either with a static server or a CDN, then the `url(https://hosted-address/images/icon.png)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. In snippet you've provided, you are setting a background-image style property , that means , that '../images/icon.png' won't work , you have to specify that as url(../images/icon.png)
2. If still won't work , try to convert your image to base64 and set is as el.style.backgroundImage = url(your base64 encoded image) , if works ,then problem with path

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your el.style.backgroundImage line to

```js
el.style.backgroundImage ='url("../images/icon.png")';
```

Or you can get rid of setting styles via JS and add them to CSS file

```css
.marker {
    background-image: url('../images/icon.png'); 
    background-size: cover;
    width: 29px; 
    height: 29px;
}
```